# Angular Animation only works on first click

Tags: angular

The animation (translateX) only works on the first click. See stackblitz example. How can I get it to work every click? Thanks

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p9strz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Angular animation callback](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#animation-callbacks) to listen to `(@block.done)` and then update the initial `translateX` of the element.

The component code should look like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  animations: [
    trigger("block", [
      state(
        "initial",
        style({
          transform: "translateX({{offset}}px)"
        }),
        { params: { offset: 0 } }
      ),
      state(
        "slide",
        style({
          transform: "translateX({{distance}}px)"
        }),
        { params: { distance: 100 } }
      ),

      transition("initial => slide", animate("900ms")),
      transition("slide => initial", animate("0ms"))
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  carouselState;
  slideDistance;
  counter = 0;
  offset = 0;

  moveBlock() {
    this.counter++;
    this.slideDistance = 100 * this.counter;
    this.carouselState = "slide";
  }

  onAnimationDone() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.offset = this.slideDistance;
      this.carouselState = 'initial';
    });
  }
}
```

and your template like this:

```html
<div class="block" 
  (@block.done)="onAnimationDone()"
  [@block]="{value: carouselState, params: {distance: slideDistance, offset: offset }}">
</div>
```

Note that I wrapped the `offset` update with `setTimeout` to defer it to the next tick.
You can find the updated stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hxducl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: is there a reason why onAnimationDone() fires twice? And setTimeout() is that really needed?

Comment: it's called twice since you have 2 animation states, so it fires on each one. the `setTimeout` is needed to defer the update or else you will get `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`